# Add icon to select dropdown

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add in an icon to the end of a select group. I've abs positioned the pseudo element but I'm unable to see it.

Markup:

```
<select id="signup-sector" name="signup-sector" class="signup-select">
                        <option value="sector">Sector</option>
                        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
                        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
                        <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
                    </select>
```

CSS:

```
select.signup-select::after {
    content: "\f107;";
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    right: 5px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: black;
}
```

The select has a position relative set.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is what i do, try this..
hope this may help you...

```css
.signup-select:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: 3px;
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    border-top: 10px solid #333;
}
```

```html
<select id="signup-sector" name="signup-sector" class="signup-select">
                        <option value="sector">Sector</option>
                        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
                        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
                        <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
                    </select>
```